# popd not working as expected

Tags: command-line, bash

It seems that `pushd` and `popd` are not working as expected (popping the last pushed directory) but it is popping the first directory and the after the second `popd` it goes to home directory.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ pushd /tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir1 ~
user@ubuntu:/tmp/dir1$ pushd /tmp/dir2
/tmp/dir2 /tmp/dir1 ~
user@ubuntu:/tmp/dir2$ cd ..
user@ubuntu:/tmp$ popd
/tmp/dir1 ~
user@ubuntu:/tmp/dir1$ popd
~
```

Any reason for this?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in VMware Workstation 12 Player

Answer (score 0):

It goes to home directory after last pop because you were in your home directory when you pushed `/tmp/dir1` onto this stack. `~` is your home directory. This part:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ pushd /tmp/dir1
/tmp/dir1 ~
```

Specifically, when the directory stack is empty, it adds current working directory to the bottom of the stack.

Here's an example from `/etc`:

```
bash-4.3$ cd /etc
bash-4.3$ pushd /usr
/usr /etc
```

The `popd` behavior is also proper, it did remove the oldest pushed directory, but you also missed the part that it goes to the new top directory after the old was removed. Read the manual again:

> popd [-n] [+n] [-n] Removes entries from the directory stack. 
>   With no arguments, **removes the  top directory**  from  the stack, and **performs a cd to the new top directory**.

So  in your case with stack `/tmp/dir2 /tmp/dir1 ~` , first `popd` removed `/tmp/dir2`. So what's the new top of the stack ? `/tmp/dir1`, so it will also perform `cd /tmp/dir1`.

Observe:

```
bash-4.3$ pwd
/etc
bash-4.3$ pushd /bin
/bin /etc
bash-4.3$ pushd /usr
/usr /bin /etc
bash-4.3$ pushd /sys
/sys /usr /bin /etc
bash-4.3$ popd
/usr /bin /etc
bash-4.3$ pwd
/usr
```